# is there a standard mtx_t 'invalid' state?

Tags: c, c11

Because there's no static initialization in C, I'd like to lazily initialize a global mtx_t (*please hold your gag reflexes*). It isn't a problem for me to use a boolean flag and whatnot, but I'd rather just check the mtx_t variable.

**Is there a blessed 'invalid state' for C11's mtx_t I can check the variable against?** I couldn't find anything in the draft standard.

Comment: I don't think there's one. C11 threads is not widely implemented and documentation is poor (in the spec itself!). So if you can't find any in the spec, then that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no such invalid state that you could check, using an uninitialized `mtx_t` leads to undefined behavior.

The whole thing of not having static initializers for `mtx_t` is a bit idiotic, on any normal architecture you can do that without problems. POSIX has it.

Also, it is easy to add enough state to a `mtx_t` to make that possible. You'd have to add

- one `volatile int` as a flag that you set to one when initialization is done
- one `atomic_flag` that you use as a spinlock in case the first flag is `0`. In that case, once you hold the spinlock

  - test the init flag again
  - if it is still `0` initialize the `mtx_t` and set the init flag to one
  - unset the `atomic_flag`

Comment: This is a very clear description of how _not_ to implement double-checked locking - there's a data race on the `volatile int` flag.